# Is it possible to connect an external mic to my phone and use it for calls?

Tags: samsung, microphone

I have a high end microphone (Neumann) and was wondering if I could somehow connect it to my phone and use it as an alternative to the built-in microphone.

Comment: What connector/plug does the microphone have?

Comment: @Robert it has an XLR connection